# Push and Insert at a time in Vuejs and PHP

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want to push the value in `Array`. It will show the value instantly. There is no need to refresh the whole page.

`app.todoList.push(this.todo)`

With this line I am doing that.

At the same time I want to insert this value to Database. Here is the problem. Differently they are working perfectly. But combined it is problem.

Here is the problem snipet.

[image]

[image]

Data:

```
todo: null,
todoList: []
```

Form to submit:

```
<form class="w-100" @submit="createTodo">
   <div class="form-group w-100">
     <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="What needs to be done? " v-model="todo">
   </div>
</form>
```

Todo Print:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="todo in todoList">
    {{ todo.todo_title }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Method of inserting data into db:

```
createTodo(e) {
  // Pushing dot only
  app.todoList.push(this.todo)
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('todo_title', this.todo)

  axios({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'api/todos.php',
       data: formData
  }).then(function(res){
  }).catch(function(res){
    console.log(res)
  });
  this.todo = null
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

What can I do to do it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters I would say that a more standard way of doing it is pushing the todo in the Axios promise callback. This way you could also include the ID that is created from the backend in the object.

It's not entirely clear what the issue is, if the issue is that you get the li but empty name, the problem is that when you're doing `app.todoList.push(this.todo)` you're printing the 'todo_title'. What you need to do is push it with the key `app.todoList.push({ todo_title: this.todo })`.

Comment: app.todoList.push({ 
                id: '',
                todo_title: this.todo,
                todo_status: 0
            })

How will I give correct ID?

Comment: In the promise from your backend (the `then` part), you can access the response from your backend via `then(res => res.data)` and providing your backend returns the created object for example `{ id: 1, todo_title: 'Title', todo_status: 0 }` you'll be able to get the id from that response.

`.then(res => { app.todoList.push(res.data) })` OR you might just get the id from your backend and then you'll have to do it more verbose:

`then(res => { app.todoList.push({ id: res.data.id, todo_title: this.todo }) })`

It all depends on your backend